# What exactly does "up to 3 months before" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

When it says:

> You can apply for a visa up to 3 months before your date of travel to
> the UK.
>
> Source: [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa)

Does it mean **the latest** I can apply for a visa is 3 months before the travel date, or the **earliest** I can apply for a visa is 3 months before the travel date?

Comment: At the level of *English language* the statement is ambiguous. Ask whoever wrote it, if the answer matters to you. ELU cannot help.

Comment: If it is so and the sentence is ambiguous, it is *also* an answer for the OP and there is no need to give him -1. I have had a strong feeling that once somebody here just does not *like* a question (and without GIVING or maybe even having an objective reason) they give minus points. I am not happy about this. I find this question useful, even if a clear answer cannot be given. I as a non-native English speaker feel this as arrogant from you native speakers.

Comment: @Honza: I haven't downvoted. Obviously in the *real* world I know that the intended sense is *"You can't apply more than 3 months in advance"*. See ["Applications received more than 3 months before your date of travel will be returned without a visa"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Applications+received+more+than+3+months+before+your+date+of+travel+will+be+returned+without+a+visa%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22Applications+received+more+than+3+months+before+your+date+of+travel+will+be+returned+without+a+visa%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5175946j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: But at the level of *language*, the text is ambiguous, so the question is Off Topic Opinion-based.

Comment: No, the question is *not* off-topic. The question is perfectly answerable! The answer is: "Even for the native speaker the sentence is ambiguous and can carry both the given meanings". I understand "Opinion-based" differently. The **question** is not ambiguous! What is ambiguous here is the **sentence under question** which is perfectly OK!

Comment: As long as _Usage_ in in the name of this site, I do not see this question as _off-topic_. This is _Usage_ of the English Language, by none less than the _government of the UK_, and it is admittedly ambiguous. I don't see how a question about that would _not_ be on-topic.

Comment: I am quite unhappy that the site seems to be turning into a kind of a snobbish arrogant native English club with members who reject questions just because they don't like them enough or because they consider them as too trivial. Without even bothering to state a clear reason - which makes their voting even more dubious. I am often completely confused why some questions are -1-ed or put on hold or closed, while they seem perfectly complying with the site policy.

And an ambiguous text is not the same as an ambiguous question! I would expect at least this distinction from you "English seniors"!

Comment: @FumbleFingers why is it off topic? "The sentence is ambiguous and can be read both ways" is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @terdon: Imho it's OT because the syntactic aspects giving rise to that ambiguity are too basic for ELU, and thus not relevant to a site aimed at [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Besides which, it seems pretty clear the OP isn't asking about the ambiguous syntax itself - he's hoping for an actual *answer* definitively telling him what time constraints apply to his visa application.

Comment: @HonzaZidek while I don't agree that this is off topic, you should realize that this site is not for people learning English. As you can see in the [on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page, this site is for "linguists and , etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts". This is in no way limited to native speakers but the scope of the site does not include questions that any native speaker would know the answer to. Our sister-site, [ell.se] was created to deal with such questions.

Comment: @terdon: Any native speaker **including the British government** would know the answer? Or the British government is excluded?

Comment: @HonzaZidek I would not presume to speak for the British government. In this case, any native speaker would know the phrase is ambiguous. However, bureaucratese is a language unto itself.

Comment: @terdon: as you may see, there is at least one *quite influential* group of native English speakers who have the opinion that the sentence is not ambiguous :) Supposed we exclude the possibility that the British government does it *on purpose* to drive away those potential visa applicants whose ability to analyse the syntactic aspects giving rise to that ambiguity lies below the level expected by the ELU community :)

Comment: Fumb -- why not just click the "close off topic" button??

Comment: "I am quite unhappy that the site seems to be turning into a kind of a snobbish arrogant native English club with members who reject questions just because they don't like them"  What a load of nonsense. **This question is way too simple and should be on ESL**. What's hard to understand about that? The problem on this site is **everyone's too polite to close crap questions.**

Comment: @JoeBlow: apparently the question is is not so simple if the British government has problems with the sentence.

Comment: This is very similar to [Was I driving more than 5 mph under the speed limit, or less than 5 mph under the speed limit?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152906/26083)

Comment: It should be noted that any native English speaker would have normally used "at least 3 months before" had the second meaning been intended.  In ordinary conversation and writing this would be sufficient for disambiguation -- it's only the fact that this is legalese where a misinterpretation could be quite inconvenient/expensive (and where wording may have been subject to editing multiple times) that makes this truly ambiguous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways in which the statement may be analysed.

> You can apply for a visa up to 3 months before your date of travel to the UK.

The ambiguity is in the interpretation of *up to:* it could mean *until* or it could mean *a maximum of*.

> You can apply for a visa until 3 months before your date of travel to the UK.
>   You can apply for a visa a maximum of 3 months before your date of travel to the UK.

In this case, *up to* should almost certainly have the second meaning. There's no point in applying for a visa years before you intend to travel, because your circumstances could change in the meantime. So the authority seeks to limit the possibility of changes by forcing you to apply fairly close to the date of travel.

Comment: The British Government publishes processing times of up to 60 days, and the web page itself says "You should get a decision on your visa within 3 weeks," so it's certainly not three months to process an application. But I have flagged the ambiguity on that web page.

Comment: The web page has (at some point in the last six years) been amended to say "The earliest you can apply is 3 months before you travel," so it is the second of the possible interpretations. It's now a beautifully clear statement.

Answer (score 3):

From a language point of view, this sentence can be parse in two ways:

1) You can apply for a visa up until a moment in time that is three months before your travel date.

2) You can apply during a period ranging from 0 to 3 months before your travel date.

Now, purely practical, the only interpretation that makes much sense in this context is the second one. Otherwise, nobody could apply for a visa unless they plan their trip more than three months in advance - and strict immigration rules may be one thing, but things like business trips (that stand to make the UK money indirectly) often come up on a shorter notice.

Comment: downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @JoeBlow nopes, but I'm in the EU. But I have some experience with immigration policies of several countries; and however big the bureaucratic workload, those policies are not designed to make ad-hoc travel impossible. Even from not-so-nice countries too much money flows in :P

Answer (score 0):

Although from the **language** point of view the sentence may be ambiguous, I am pretty sure that in the given context the correct meaning **intended by the immigration office** is the second - you may first apply for the visa 3 months before your travel.

The sentence structure is like this:

- up to 3 months = 0 to 3 months, but not more
- up to 3 months before the date = 0 to 3 months before the date

[image]

Comment: That is not necessarily the case. The other interpretation is perfectly valid, too, in which you can apply for a visa up until a point in time that is three months before the date of travel, but not after that. The phrasing is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The emigration office is imprecise and ambiguous. It should be "no sooner" or "no later" than 3 month before date of travel.

In addition, the regulations also say that the office has 30 days to process the application, so it cannot necessarily be that we can apply at any time during the three-month period before the date of travel (e.g. two days before departure).

Comment: Hello, Wojtek. 'The [instructions are] imprecise, ambiguous.' This answer has  been given already. The rest of your comments, while probably quite valid, do not address the title question but (a) suggest a sensible replacement (as other answers have done) and (b) suggest how further information _not directly supplied by OP in the actual question_ may suggest (but not force) one rather than the other of the two possible interpretations. But this does not answer the original question as presented. ELU was never intended to be an interpretation service: way beyond remit.